# phone whilstles or bell rings: sounds on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: notifications, custom-sounds

I have two very basic questions about my Samsung Galaxy S3 phone. In its
default configuration:

1. Every now and then the phone whistles. (a) What does this mean?
   (b) How do I change this or turn it off permanently?
2. A few months ago the operating system did an OTA (over-the-air) update.
   Now every now and then, besides this whistling, I also hear a bicycle bell
   ringing. (a) What does this mean and how does this differ from the whistling,
   that is, how is the information conveyed by the whistling different by the
   information conveyed by the bicycle bell ringing? (b) How do I change this
   sound or turn it off altogether permanently?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

These are both notifications. To change them or even just find out what they are notifying you about go to Settings > My Device > Sound
You can change the "Default Notification Sound" (even choosing silent, but then you won't get any notification sounds) and a little bit lower on the menu you can set distinct defaults for specific samsung apps. There are many apps that allow you to choose different notifications sounds (other than the default that you chose above), but those have to be changed in the apps themselves.

Do you notice any new information in the notification area (by swiping down from the top of the screen) when you hear these alerts?

Comment: Thanks. I can see the Whistle sound under Settings -> My Device -> Default Notification Sound but cannot find the bicycle bell sound there. If I set this to silent will the bicycle bell sound go away as well? Thanks.

Comment: @JohnSonderson Every app can control its own notifications. When the bell rings what exactly happens on the device when this rings? It was emails for me, but it does depend on the app.

Comment: I think the bicycle sound is called "Postman" on an sgs3. Did you look in all of the apps listed under "samsung applications" (Call, Message, Email, Splanner)?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I found the sound under `Settings -> My device -> Sound -> Default notification sound (open with Media Storage) -> Postman` (the default here is set to Whistle). That is exactly the sound I was looking for (the reason I was not finding it is that I was probably looking under `Ringtones`). However I cannot find an application called "samsung applications", although I have an application called "GALAXY Apps". Is this the one I should be looking at? Some app keeps on making that "Postmap" notification sound ring, and I'm not sure where to look. Thanks.

Comment: I think the "Samsung Applications" section of the Sounds menu  is found in android version 4.4, you probably have version 4.3. Galaxy Apps is not what you want, that is another app store like Google Play.